# Why does my program that sorts an array in ascending order produce garbage values?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swa(int *, int *);
int main()
{
    int i,j,arr[10];
    arr[10]= (10,20,30,40,50);
    printf("ascending order");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]<arr[j]);
            swa(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",arr[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
void swa(int *x,int *y)
{
    int t;
    t=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=t;
}
```

This code is giving garbage values in output. How can I modify this program using a function say `swa` for swapping?

Comment: If a function is for swapping, you should really name it `swap` or `swapInts` or `swapIntegers` instead of `swa`.

Comment: Did you check if you don't have garbage values before you start to sort? Note that `arr[10]` is not a valid index, nor does it, as you seem to think, represent the entire array. Also note that `(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)` is just equivalent to `50`. That is not the way to initialize an array. See answer by @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: In other words, the fact that something compiles does not mean it actually does what you think it should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array can be initialized when it is declared using a braced list.

Thus this attempt to initialize the array

```
int i,j,arr[10];
arr[10]= (10,20,30,40,50);
```

is invalid. In fact in the second statement in the right side there is used the comma operator and a non-existent element of the array with index 10 is assigned to 50.

This if statement

```
if (arr[i]<arr[j]);
                  ^^
```

has an empty sub-statement due to the incorrectly placed semicolon. It must be removed.

Moreover the condition in the if statement says that you are trying to sort the array in the descending order instead of the ascending order.

Also it is a bad style of programming to use magic numbers as for example number 5 in your program.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int *x, int *y )
{
    int tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{

    int arr[N] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    size_t i, j;

    size_t n = 0;
    while ( n < N && arr[n] != 0 ) ++n;

    printf( "descending order:" );

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[i] < arr[j] ) swap( &arr[i], &arr[j] );
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( " %d", arr[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
descending order: 50 40 30 20 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty close, but you've made three mistakes:

- You initialize array using a comma expression,
- You put a semicolon after your `if`, and
- You are swapping in the wrong direction (your array would be sorted in descending order) - i.e. `if (arr[i]<arr[j])` should be `if (arr[i]>arr[j])`

Fixing these three mistakes will produce a working solution. Initialization needs to happen as part of a declaration, and use curly braces:

```
int i,j,arr[10] = {10,30,50,40,20};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ydQXJk)

Answer (score 0):

1. init of array at wrong place.
2. sorting is not correct
3. semicolon after if statement preventing from swaping.

change it to:

```
    int i,j,arr[10]= {10,20,30,40,50};

        printf("ascending order");

        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(j=i;j<(5-i-1);j++)
            {
                if (arr[j]>arr[j+1])
                swa(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
```